# Emulator of AOSP not booting. ADB shell 'exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory (2)'

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

After running

```
  source build/envsetup.sh  
  lunch full-eng
  make
  emulator
```

Emulator window shows up blank as if the system is not booting.
Same happens when trying to make with `lunch aosp_x86-eng`
`emulator -verbose` [doesn't show any errors](http://pastebin.com/WbdcDd92) or something out of the ordinary.

When running `adb shell` I'm now getting `- exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory (2) -`

I tried running `make clobber` and then `make` again, but it didn't help.
Also tried syncing the entire codebase again with `repo init .... && repo sync` and didn't change anything (`repo diff` shows there are no changes to the code). Running `emulator -no-window` still doesn't yield any better result as `adb shell` still won't work.

For a little while last week, the emulator was working, but then stopped, and `adb devices` would show `device offline`.

I cannot seam to find a way to get some more verbose output of what is causing issue. My suspicion is that I have something stuck in some global environment directory (already tried reseting the computer, and deleting the ~/.android dir)

I'm running on a MacbookPro with Mountain Lion. Intel HAX installed.

Anyone could have some direction?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the AOSP master branch is not stable. Make sure when doing `repo init` to use the `-b` and check out a stable tag/branch